# variable and variable manupulation in URL

Tags: php, regex, string, url

Hi I'm having a requirement where I need to capture all variables and its value.

The URL need not be `www.sample.com?a=1&b=2`, it can be `www.sample.com/a=1/b=2` or `www.sample.com/a=1&b=2&c=3`, then in this which way it would be efficient, fast & good to use so that there would not be any data loss?

I have explored functions like `strtok`,`strpos`,`substr`, etc. But non of them is serving for my purpose. Any help would be highly appreciated.

i was thinking of using `strtok` with `=` in a loop(length of number of times `=`) where it will give  `a then b so on` so that i will use a function to get the value between `a=` and `&`

Comment: To help with finding it: php.net/parse_url

It is very helpful function. Best of luck!

Comment: Anubhava FYI `parse_url` will not return the variable if link will be like this `www.sample.com/a=1/b=2` for parse_url to work it must have `?`

Comment: parse_url is good for standard urls, but it can't handle arbitrary 'clean' urls and turn `/a=1/b=2` into $_GET equivalents. That's not its job.

Comment: i was thinking of using `strtok` in a loop(length of number of times `=`) where it will give be a then b then so that i will use a function to get the value between a= and & and consecutively

Comment: My best suggestion would be to have a list of "valid" delimiters stored somewhere.
Then you can try delimiting by each "Valid" delimiter.
Then you can compare your results from every valid delimiter and take the result tokens from the delimiter that gave you the largest string array(or the one that gave you +-1 from the number of = signs. (or a variant of this algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

You start with an .htaccess file with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
## Internally rewrite extensionless file requests to .php files ## 
# If the requested URI does not contain a period in the final path-part 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$ 
# and if it does not exist as a directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# and if it does not exist as a file 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
# then add .php to get the actual filename 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/? index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

This will send the complete url to `$_GET[q]`, if the url is not an directory or file.
After that, there are a few options you can do. I'll give you one example:

```
function gatherUrlInfo($url){
    $url = trim($url, "/"); remove all slashes in the beginning or end
    $url = explode("/", $url); // get 'a=1', 'b=2', .. seperately
    $result = array();
    foreach($url as $k=>$value){
        $values = explode("=", $value); // get the a and 1  seperately
        $result[$values[0]] = $values[1];
    }
}

print_r( gatherUrlInfo($_GET['q']) );// will be array("a"=>'1', "b"=>'2');
```

Comment: Martinjn we can't manipulate the way you suggested. it needs to be there in same format. some third party clients are associated!

Comment: I don't understand? The url is the way you suggested... the `index.php` is only for you php, the url doenst change